# how to insert data, using select in excel

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, oledb

I have data large data to insert in excel, all data is came from sql server, i want to prepare insert query which will insert bunch of records at a time like..

```
INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] (ID,Name)
SELECT '1' AS ID,'XYZ' AS Name UNION
SELECT '1' AS ID,'XYZ' AS Name UNION
SELECT '1' AS ID,'XYZ' AS Name
```

but it will giving me an error like

```
Query input must contain at least one table or query.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this option.

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\testing.xlsx;;HDR=YES;IMEX=1', 'SELECT Id, Name FROM [Sheet1$]')
SELECT '1' AS ID,'XYZ' AS Name
UNION ALL
SELECT '1' AS ID,'XYZ' AS Name 
UNION ALL
SELECT '1' AS ID,'XYZ' AS Name
```

Here i assume that you have already enable the **Ad Hoc Distributed Queries** option in your sql server.

Comment: I have configured 

Exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
 
Exec sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'AllowInProcess' , 1; 
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'DynamicParameters' , 1;
GO

but still getting error like 

Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.

Comment: Here i m using **Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0** bcs i have installed Microsoft Office 2007 in my system. You can try with **Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0** and let me know...

Comment: I have installed Office 2010 64bit on my system, so OLEDB4.0 is not working for me..
I have also installed Microsoft Access Engine 64bit, my system is Win 7 64bit and also my SQL server 2008 is 64bit